# WooCommerce API получает только 10 товаров и 10 категории

Tags: java, wordpress, telegram-bot, woocommerce, maven

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня сайт на WordPress + WooCommerce, получаю API на json из:

https://[тут мой сайт]/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=[тут ключ]&consumer_secret=[тут секретный ключ]
получаю только 10 продуктов (на сайте около 200 продуктов, пока что)

https://[тут мой сайт]/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/?consumer_key=[тут ключ]&consumer_secret=[тут секретный ключ]
получаю только 10 категории (на сайте 12 категории)

Есть ли где-то в настройках ограничение или типа того.

Comment: Ну и метки, прямо по теме...

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `per_page=200`

```
https://[тут мой сайт]/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=[тут ключ]&consumer_secret=[тут секретный ключ]&per_page=200
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, да "per_page=200" и в правду работает, только у него есть лимит, после "=" можно написать от 1 до 100, а 200 он не принимает, и если  я ввиду 100 тогда получу только 100 товаров (